# How to create observable from service using `rxjs` in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am getting a serer value from one of the component. the component is getting from backend. once it's done it's sending to service.

from footer component I am getting the data from service. if I console the value it shows as `undefined`. if I use `setTimeout` like follows, it works.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StorageService } from '../shared/service/storage.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private storage:StorageService) {
        setTimeout(()=> console.log( this.storage.socialNetworks ), 1000 ); //how to achive the same using Observable?
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

Comment: show `storage` service

Comment: rxjs has a website you know: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/timeout.html

Comment: Well probably `this.storage.socialNetworks` isn't set by the time this component is created. You can eventually put it into `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing a proper example of your code (including what StorageService is) it is hard.

(For your info, this could be made much more *smart* for example, store the data in a behaviorSubject in the service, and/or share the subscription to prevent duplicate AJAX requests (if this is being subscribed to many times over)).

But this is the *general* pattern:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenService {

    private apiBaseUrl = ''; // <- some url here.

    loadSocialNetworks(): Observable<any> {
        const myEndpoint = 'socialNetworks'; // <- user correct endpoint name
        return this.http.get(`apiBaseUrl${myEndpoint}`)
            .map((response) => response.json());
    }

    // ....other code
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

    socialNetworks: any;

    constructor(private storage:StorageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.storage.loadSocialNetworks()
            .subscribe((socialNetworks) => this.socialNetworks);
    }

}
```